# Multiple "Main Queue" Tasks For User Perspective

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch

This is perhaps more existential than a concrete question, but I'm struggling with a bit of a user experience issue in my app.

In my app, I have a task that converts a UIView to an UIImage, does some off-screen processing, and updates the UI for the user.  All of this happens on the Main Queue, as is required for such UIKit tasks.

I want to have an activity indicator in my app (I'm using a custom designed one, but a regular UIActivityIndicator demonstrates the same issue), which I also have running on the Main Queue, prior to the aforementioned task.

My issue is that once the UIView processing kicks in, my activity indicator freezes until the task completes.  This is obviously due to the main queue handling another, more intensive task, hereby hanging the spinner.  My curiosity is; how can I ensure the spinner continues, regardless of the UI work happening on the main queue?

Thanks!

Comment: I wouldn't call it existential but it is certainly vague. What is "does some off-screen processing"? I doubt that that can't be on the background thread. UIImage work on a background thread is perfectly legal.

Comment: At the very least, I'd suggest moving the suggest moving the "some off-screen processing" to a background queue. In terms of further optimization, we'd need to know what sort of stuff you're rendering in the view into the image. E.g. In WWDC 2012 [Building Concurrent User Interfaces on iOS](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2012/211/), Apple shows how certain complicated rendering can be moved off the main thread, too. But that latter point applies to a narrow set of circumstances, so we'd need to know what you're rendering into the `UIImage` to coment further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid this is impossible unless you do the heavyweight operation on the background thread.

You can try to give the main thread a little bit air to breathe by chunking the operation to smaller parts, if that can be done. That would at least allow some updates of the spinner.

While I think that you should keep taking an image and updating the UI on the main thread, considering putting processing the image at the background thread, if that is possible.

Comment: Who would downvote this???? Okay, I'm upvoting just to counteract the fool who downvoted it.

Comment: I'm marking this correct.  Your suggestions got me on a path to rethinking the order in which I do things, and also giving the app time to breathe.  While I've simply just created too complex a set of tasks that need to occur, this has given me ideas to rethink things from a UX standpoint.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Milan. I'd suggest a slightly different flow:

Start your activity indicator spinning.

Grab your view and convert it to an image.

Pass the image processing to a GCD background queue for processing, and pass in a completion handler.

When the background processing is complete, invoke the completion handler on the main thread. In the body of the completion handler, stop/hide the activity indicator.

Comment: I doubt that the completion handler is needed. He can probably just use the normal GCD flow of nested `async` calls from main queue to background queue to main queue.

Comment: True, a completion handler wouldn't be required.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest something like this.

```
 -(void)render {
        startSpinner();
        backgroundRenderQueue = dispatch_queue_create("backgroundQueue",DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT); 
        dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, ^{

            //Render image here
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context)]; 
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                self.imageview.image = image;
                stopeSpinner()
            });
        });
    }
```